# Showing that an epimorphism of an ideal is again an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R, S$ be commutative rings, $f : R \rightarrow S$ an epimorphism, I an ideal of R. Show that $f(I)$ is an ideal of $S$.

As far as I understand, I need to show 4 things:

1) $0_s \in f(I)$

2) $sf(i) \in f(I), f(i)s \in f(I) \ \forall s \in S \ \forall f(i) \in f(I)$

and the subgroup properties

3) $f(a) + f(b) \in f(I) \ \forall a,b \in I$

4) $f(a)^{-1} \in f(I) \ \forall a \in I$

that's what I have so far:

1) $I$ ideal of R $\Rightarrow 0_R \in I \Rightarrow_{f(0_R) = 0_S} 0_S \in f(I)$

2)

$f$ surjective $\Rightarrow \exists s' \in R : f(s') = s$. $sf(i) = f(s')f(i) = f(\underbrace{s'i}_{\in I}) \in f(I)$.

(and the other direction similar).

3) $f(a) + f(b) = f(\underbrace{a + b}_{\in I}) \in f(I)$

4) I tried a few approaches, but didn't succeed in this part. Can you help me to show why the inverse element exists?

Is my approach correct?

Comment: You don't need to show closure under multiplicative inverses. In fact, if an ideal contains an invertible element, then the ideal contains $1$, and so so is the entire ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^{-1} \in I \Rightarrow f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1} \in f(I)$

EDIT:(as Simon suggested)

There is no need for inverse to show ideal

Comment: thank you for your answer! Do 1) - 3) look correct for you?

Comment: You are welcome. 1)-3) look fine to me